# Jumping between blocks in VSCode like in WebStorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

Is it possible to jump between blocks in VSCode like in WebStorm? For example:

**WebStorm:**

```html
|<div class="test"></div>
```

And when I press <kbd>Option + Arrow Right</kbd> a few times the caret lands here:

```html
<div class="test">|</div>
```

**VSCode:**

```html
|<div class="test"></div>
```

And when I press <kbd>Option + Arrow Right</kbd> a few times it lands here.
To enter the block I have to press the left arrow twice.

```html
<div class="test"></|div>
```

Legend:

- "|" represents caret

Can anyone help with setup if this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something for you: [Jump Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ysemeniuk.jump-tag)

> Caution: this extension overrides default Ctrl + Alt + Right and Ctrl + Alt + Left shortcuts. To change this go File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

Hope this help. I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

With the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and the command `moveby.regex` you can setup a regex to search forward or backward.

You probably need to search for `<` or `>` and place cursor at the start or end of the searched string.

It also works with Multi Cursor.